# Setting Charge Webhook in config file

Tags: plugin-charge

How do I set the webhook URL for Charge in the config file?

I've got my /config/charge.php created.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
<?php

return [
    'webhook' => 'http://example.com',
];
```